# Watir: Download in headless-chrome working in windows not in Linux

Tags: selenium, watir, headless-browser

I am using headless chrome with Watir.

The below code for download path working in windows but not in Linux. In Linux, the file is getting downloaded but not to the specified path. Instead, it is downloaded to the path where the script is being run from.

```
        download_dir = File.join(File.absolute_path('', File.dirname(__FILE__)),"files/temp")
        download_dir.gsub! '/','\\'
        prefs = {
            download: {
              prompt_for_download: false,
              directory_upgrade: true,
              default_directory: download_dir
            }
          }
          client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
          client.read_timeout = 300 # seconds

        chrom_options = {:args=>['window-size=1920x1080','headless','disable-gpu'],:prefs=> prefs}
        Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :http_client => client, options: chrom_options, :listener => ActionListener.new
```

Tried removing this line for Linux, still the same result.

```
download_dir.gsub! '/','\\'
```

What could be the issue ?

Comment: Are you getting any error message in the console? And do es the donwload_dir exist in the linux box?

Comment: No, I am not getting any error messages.

Comment: check the chrome version, there was a change around v79 I believe